# Selecting intersecting elements that have same value in another attribute and merging them into one using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have a polyline shapefile "rivers" containing three columns:

```
[Start,  End,  Meas]
[1,     2,     3]
[2,     3,     3]
[2,     4,     2]
[4,     5,     3]
[5,     6,     3]
```

What I want to do is inside a for loop test all elements in the shapefile (large number)
If Start of one element = End of another element & Meas is the same the join the 2 elements.

The result would be:

```
[Start,  End,  Meas]

[1,     3,     3]
[2,     4,     2]
[4,     6,     3]
```

Any ideas how to do this (merge 5 elements into 3 elements) in arcpy?

I mostly want these 2 elements to be merged spatially. Don't really care if the Start and end columns are updated by the script correctly..

A small sample of my attribute table:

[image]

What I am trying to do is a for loop.. I think that I have to use cursors, but I am new at this.. My for loop is like this but cant assign to literal (Of course maybe I am completely wrong about this): `>>>

```
... for i in "Channels2020":
...     temp3=["NODE_A"]
...     temp3a=["ORDER"]
...     temp3b=["SEGMENT_ID"]
...     for k in "Channels2020":
...         temp4a["NODE_B"]
...         temp4a=["ORDER"]
...         temp4b=["SEGMENT_ID"]
...         if temp3b!=temp4b & temp3==temp4 & temp3a==temp4a:
...             ["SEGMENT_ID"]=temp3b
```

Comment: Do you have networkx library (import networkx?), then a start could be: [Group sublists with common elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56074313/group-sublists-with-common-elements)

Comment: You have tried dissolve tool?

Comment: I tried.. And I don't have the networkx library.. Trying to see how to get it.. Yes I tried the dissolve tool but doesn't work as I want to in the large database I have..

Comment: Thanks for the help! I attached a screenshot of my complete attribute table. NODE_A and NODE_B are start and end node respectively for each segment. Yes I have pandas library

Comment: Nice. Can you share the table as text? For example export as csv and upload to https://justpaste.it/? Or add a long enough sample as text to your question

Comment: NODE_A, NODE_B, ORDER

Comment: What are a few lines that can be added prior to those you've presented which would enable a potential answerer to run it?  Please present a code snippet without the leading ellipses (…) on each line.